# Эмуляция мобильного устройства на сервере

Tags: node.js

Хотелось бы иметь возможность создавать посты в Инстаграме с сервера ( сервер на Node.js). Но Инстаграм дает возможность постить только с моб. устройств.Возникла идея эмуляции мобильного устройства на сервере,а с него уже отсылать данные на сервер Инстаграма.
Насколько это реально? Или возможно я занимаюсь велосипедостроениеем, и есть более лекгие пути решения проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) - это полноценный эмулятор Android телефона, без поддержки голосовой связи и СМС, но с поддержкой TCP/IP - особенность в том, что эмулятор крутится в виртуальной машине [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) - то есть если руки не сильно кривые то его можно поднять на более-менее любом сервере, ну а дальше что-нибудь приписать к нему чтобы постил на Instagram, установка Instagram на GenyMotion не должна вызвать непреодолимых препятствий. Достаточно будет установки Google Play Market - например [смотрите здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su).